# If and only if?

Tags: logic

Is the statement true or false?

New Jersey is a state if and only if Florida is not a state?

Florida is a state?

So that will be false?

Is this the way it works?

Comment: It's a different statement than "New Jersey is a state AND Florida is not a state."

Comment: Could you please use less question marks?

Answer (score 3):

An "if and only if" statement is true according to whether the truth values of the two statements match. Here, they do not match, so the statement is false.

Answer (score 1):

The statement "New Jersey is a state if and only if Florida is not a state", is the same thing as saying, "$\,$'If New Jersey is a state then Florida is not a state' and 'if Florida is not a state then New Jersey is a state'$\,$".

Since the statement, "if New Jersey is a state then Florida is not a state" is false, the original statement is false too.